# find emails in text with python and regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract emails from text.  I used `re.search`, which returned the 1. occurrence, but then I went on and used `re.findall`. To my surprise `re.findall` finds less emails than `re.search`. What could be the problem?

Code:

```
searchObj = re.search( r'[A-Za-z0-9\._+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+', text)
        if searchObj:
            mail = searchObj.group()
            if mail not in emails:
                emails.add(mail)

listEmails = re.findall( r'[A-Za-z0-9\._+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+', text)
        for mail in listEmails:
            if mail not in emails:
                emails.add(mail)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the capturing group `(\.|-)` with a non-capturing one or even with a character class:

```
r'[A-Za-z0-9._+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+[.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+'
                               ^^^^
```

Or even shorter:

```
r'[\w.+-]+@[^\W_]+[.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+'
```

Else, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will only return the list of captured values.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/4wbHf0):

```
import re
rx = r'[\w.+-]+@[^\W_]+[.-][A-Za-z0-9.-]+'
s = 'some@mail.com and more email@somemore-here.com'
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['some@mail.com', 'email@somemore-here.com']
```

Comment: Can you negate a group inside a character class. `[^(\d+.\d+)]`?

Comment: No, not that way. The solution depends on what you need to achieve in the end. A [tempered greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) might help.